# VueJS handing prop down to child fails

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Currently working on a product editor in VueJS, I'm running into issues with passing data from a parent to a child of a child. The structure is as follows:

`<ProductEdit>`

- Loads the product data from an API
- Contains a router-view with child routes that selectively loads a tab's content
- Router element has `:product.sync="product"` to pass data on to the router views

`<ProductOverview>`

- One of the tabs loaded by the router-view
- Receives data from the router to work with.
- Can work with the product data, display the data directly in the template of this file.
- Contains `<ProductFeatureList>`

`<ProductFeatureList>`

- Also has `:product.sync="product"`, should get the data from the parent `<ProductOverview>`
- Gets undefined instead.

### Code

#### Router

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/product/:max_id',
      name: 'ProductEdit',
      component: ProductEdit,
      children: [
        {
          alias: '',
          path: 'overview',
          name: 'ProductOverview',
          component: ProductOverview,
          props: true
        },
       ...
      ]
    ...
    }
  ]
})
```

#### ProductEdit

```
export default {
  name: 'ProductEdit',
  data: () => ({
    product: {},
    productLoaded: false
  }),
  created: function () {
    Vue.axios.get('http://api.local/products/' + this.$route.params.id).then((response) => {
      this.product = response.data.data
      // Verify if the product is actually loaded properly
      if ('id' in this.product) {
        this.productLoaded = true
      }
    })
  }
}
```

#### ProductOverview

```
export default {
  name: 'ProductOverview',
  components: {ProductFeatureList},
  props: ['product'],
  data: () => ({
    props: {
      product: {
        type: Object
      }
    }
  })
}
```

#### ProductFeatureList

```
export default {
  name: 'ProductFeatureList',
  params: ['product'],
  data: () => ({
    props: {
      product: {
        type: Object
      }
    }
  })
}
```

So the question is: Why does `<ProductFeatureList>` not get the product data from the `<ProductOverview?`?

Comment: Why do you put your `product` object inside of a `props` object in `ProductOverview`'s `data` function? `ProductFeatureList` doesn't even have a "real" props, it's just an object in the `data` function.

Comment: @BennettDams This is for [prop validation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation) see propC in the example.

Comment: @BennettDams Well, that apparently resolved the whole issue. Damn me and my blindness. I'm surprised this didn't happen in `<ProductOverview>` as well. Thank you kindly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ProductFeatureList` doesn't have proper `props` to receive passed data, as you're using an object called `props` inside of the `data` function (which is very misleading).

Pull `props` out of `data`:

**ProductFeatureList**

```
export default {
  name: 'ProductFeatureList',
  params: ['product'],
  props: {
    product: Object
  },
  data: () => ({
    somethingElse: null
  })
}
```